# Why is my JavaScript function adding increasingly more rows?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a document with many buttons, all of which contain `onclick="myFunction()"` inside the button tag.  When I click the 1st button, 1 row is added to my table, as desired.  However, as I click the 2nd button, 2 rows are added to my table, and so on, i.e. rows are added on the ith button click.  How can I fix my JavaScript function to only add 1 row for each new button click?

```
function myFunction() {
  table_body = document.getElementById("t_body");
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let element = e.target;
    if (element.tagName == "BUTTON") {
      row = table_body.insertRow();
      cell1 = row.insertCell();
      cell1.innerHTML = element;
      cell2 = row.insertCell();
      cell2.innerHTML = element.id;
      cell3 = row.insertCell();
      cell3.innerHTML = element.id;
      cell4 = row.insertCell();
      cell4.innerHTML = element.id;
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#004d00";
      element.style.color = "white";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: We need more revelant code to see what's going on, like where are your buttons for example? create a working snippet to replicate the issue [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would share more code to see what's happening. Initially looks like you can be adding multiple event listeners to BUTTON.

try target the button by a class. and make sure myFunction is only called once.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td><BUTTON class='form-button' id='example' >TEST</BUTTON></td>
        <td>example</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<br>
<script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        myFunction();
      });
      
       function myFunction() {
          table_body = document.getElementById("table");
          document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          console.log('clicked');
              let element = e.target;
              if(element.classList.contains('form-button')) {
                  row = table_body.insertRow()
                  cell1 = row.insertCell();
                  cell1.innerHTML = 'Hello';
                  cell2 = row.insertCell();
                  cell2.innerHTML = element.id;
                  element.style.backgroundColor = '#004d00';
                  element.style.color = 'white';
              }
          });
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I removed the onclick="myFunction()" from my button tags, and now all is working as intended.